Why does this foreign key constraint error appear?
I am trying to insert email and generated sessionId into a table in my mysql database (using Sequelize-TypeScript), I first check if the user exists and if the given passwords match. If this is the case, I execute the insert (create) query but it gives me the following error message: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (hyteams.sessions, CONSTRAINT sessions_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES users (email)).
I tried checking the sequelize models to see if something was wrong with those, but they seem to be fine.
import { Column, DataType, Model, Table } from "sequelize-typescript";

@Table({
    tableName: "users",
    timestamps: true
})
export default class SequelizeUserModel extends Model {
    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    })
    declare email: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: false
    })
    declare username: string;
}

import { Column, DataType, Model, Table } from "sequelize-typescript";
@Table({
    tableName: "sessions",
    timestamps: true
})
export default class SequelizeSessionModel extends Model {
    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        references: {
            model: "users",
            key: "email"
        }
    })
    declare email: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    })
    declare sessionid: string;
}

    public async findUser(email: string): Promise<User | null> {
            const find: SequelizeUserModel | null = await SequelizeUserModel.findOne({ where: { email: email } });
            if (find && find.email) {
                return this.userMapping.mapUser(find);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public async setSessionId(sessionId: string, email: string): Promise<string> {
            const create: SequelizeSessionModel | null = await SequelizeSessionModel.create({ email: email, sessionid: sessionId });
            const createdSession: SequelizeSessionModel | null = await SequelizeSessionModel.findOne({ where: { email: email, sessionid: sessionId } });
            if (createdSession && createdSession.sessionid) {
                return createdSession.sessionid;
            } else {
                throw new Error("Failed to set session id.");
            }
        }


You can use SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS in a mysql client to get more detailed information about the error. Look for the section in the status output with the heading "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR". This will show you the email value it tried to insert into sessions that caused the error. Is it trying to insert the value you thought it was?

@BillKarwin I just tried this, and the emails do match up

What does the latest foreign key error say about the reason for the error?

@BillKarwin I have resolved the issue, the problem was my model was not correctly setup as I already had a sessionId for this user but I didn't have a many to many relationship, this was only one to many. But thanks for trying to help. Also sorry for my late response, I was working all day yesterday and most of today.
